# Crispy forms inline radio button doesn't work for me

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

```
class RatingForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, lista_de_productores, **kwargs):
    super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for p in lista_de_productores:
        CHOICES = (('1', '1',), ('2', '2',), ('3', '3',) , ('4', '4',) , ('5', '5',))

        self.fields[str(p)] = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=CHOICES)

        helper = FormHelper()

        helper.layout = Layout(
                InlineRadios(str(p))
            )
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but this just displays normal radio buttons instead of inline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple oversight: in your `__init__` method, you need to set the `self.helper` property, rather than creating a variable named `helper`. This should work for you:

```
class RatingForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, lista_de_productores, **kwargs):
        super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for p in lista_de_productores:
            CHOICES = (('1', '1',), ('2', '2',), ('3', '3',) , ('4', '4',) , ('5', '5',))

            self.fields[str(p)] = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)

            # set the self.helper property:
            self.helper = FormHelper()

            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                InlineRadios(str(p))
            )
```